# Formula to gather multiple values on Vlookup function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i know its not possible, but i need a way I can look at a data set such as:

```
HAZDAMAGE   2   164601
HAZDAMAGE   2   228934
MHAZ-001    168 38838
MHAZ-001    168 82843
```

and return those values in the third column into rows underneath the main column:

```
HAZDAMAGE   MHAZ-001
164601      38838 
228934      82843
```

I've been having a hard time figuring out a good formula to use

Comment: You know it's not possible? Then why are you asking? :P But seriously, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: So you need to pick up all the matching values in the 3rd column (164601, 228934, etc) that correspond to the lookup column (sample value 'HAZDAMAGE') and assemble them across a single row. Is that what you want?

Comment: I updated the original post.  sorry for not being more clear.  i've attempted doing something like a &"-"&key but it will not work on new columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you said you tried is the right way to do this, using a helper column.  I'd create another column that keeps a count of how many times each value has appeared so far concatenated with the value itself. In your case something like this in the fourth column D (and fill the formula down):

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)&"-"&A1
```

Then wherever you want to list all the matches (suppose your first list heading is in F1), you could do this with index match (and then fill down to get subsequent matches):

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$4,MATCH(ROW(A1)&"-"&F$1,$D$1:$D$4,0))
```

Comment: genius.  much appreciated.